# I would like to add couple of fields from a collection(Release) into another collection(Story)based on matching conditions(ID) in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Collection: Story ( This is the main collection where 2 fields from the release collection needs to be appended.)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d131d93e2838c3b753e6631"),
    "expand" : "schema,names",
    "total" : 2,
    "issues" : [ 
        {
            "expand" : "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id" : "131",
            "fields" : {
                "updateddate" : "2019-06-12T10:58:12.345+0530",

                "fixVersions" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "10008",
                        "description" : "New Release 2",
                        "name" : "New Release 2"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id" : "10009",
                        "description" : "New Release 3",
                        "name" : "New Release 3"
                    }
                ],
                "aggregatetimespent" : null
            }
        },
        {
            "expand" : "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id" : "10032",
            "fields" : {
                "updateddate" : "2019-06-22T10:58:12.345+0530",

                "fixVersions" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "10008",
                        "description" : "New Release 2",
                        "name" : "New Release 2"
                    }
                ],
                "aggregatetimespent" : null
            }
        }       

    ]
}
```

Collection: Release( This is another collection with few fields from which fields)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d131a35e2838c3b753e6626"),
    "id" : "10008",
    "startDate" : "2019-06-28",
    "releaseDate" : "2019-07-05"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d131a35e2838c3b753e6626"),
    "id" : "10009",
    "startDate" : "2019-08-28",
    "releaseDate" : "2019-09-05"
}
```

Start date and Release Date need to be appended to the array fields based on the condition.
Expected output:

Collection: Story

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d131d93e2838c3b753e6631"),
    "expand" : "schema,names",
    "total" : 2,
    "issues" : [ 
        {
            "expand" : "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id" : "131",
            "fields" : {
                "updateddate" : "2019-06-12T10:58:12.345+0530",

                "fixVersions" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "10008",
                        "description" : "New Release 2",
                        "name" : "New Release 2",   
                        "startDate" : "2019-06-28",
                        "releaseDate" : "2019-07-05"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "id" : "10009",
                        "description" : "New Release 3",
                        "name" : "New Release 3",    
                        "startDate" : "2019-08-28",
                        "releaseDate" : "2019-09-05"
                    }
                ],
                "aggregatetimespent" : null
            }
        },
        {
            "expand" : "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id" : "10032",
            "fields" : {
                "updateddate" : "2019-06-22T10:58:12.345+0530",

                "fixVersions" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "10008",
                        "description" : "New Release 2",
                        "name" : "New Release 2", 
                        "startDate" : "2019-06-28",
                        "releaseDate" : "2019-07-05"
                    }
                ],
                "aggregatetimespent" : null
            }
        }       

    ]
}
```